# Difference between .exe and .pe files?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compilation, exe, portable-executable

When compiling visual studio c# applications PE and EXE files will generate. 
So what main difference between PE and EXE file? 
As i know PE file contains

```
PE/COFF Headers,
CLR Headers,
CLR Data,
Meta Data,
IL code,
.data,.text...
```

than what exe contains?.How  PE differ from EXE?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Portable Executables** (*PE*) are files that contain all the necessary information for the operating system to correctly load executable code (*.exe*, *.dll*, ...)

This may include dynamic library references for [linking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker), resource management, [TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage) data, among other things.

**Executables** (*.exe*), however, are the files that denote the main execution point on a computer program, that is, speaking in C# terms, the file that contains the **Main** function or entry point.

Answer (score 3):

.exe files are a subset of PE files, while PE files include .exe, .dll and .ocx files.

Answer (score 2):

So, `PE`stands for Portable Executable which is the file **format** for executable binaries in Windows 32bits and 64bits environments.

In my understanding, the information inside the generated `PE`file would consist in:

- Headers
- Metadadata
- CLR Data segments

However, the IL Code would be inside the `EXE` file, since it is supposed to be platform independent and it will be compiled to native code when you run the application (`Just-in time-compiler`). The `PE`section is also in charge of the initialisation of the CLR.

Keep in mind the `PE` section can be **inside** the executable file, which make more sense in most applications.